# How can I unregister from a JMS message group without killing the entire consumer (ActiveMQ)

Tags: java, jms, load-balancing, activemq-classic, distributed-computing

In my distributed application, I am dispatching processing requests to a JMS queue. I have multiple nodes consuming from that queue (load balancing). Processing the requests requires a rather large chunk of user-specific data to be loaded into memory and I obviously want to keep that data in memory for subsequent requests. Thus, I'm using JMSXGroupId with the user-id to make sure, that all requests for a specific user are handled by the node that already has the data cached.

After some time, when the user is no longer active, I want to unload the data on the node. At that same time, I would like that node to give up ownership of the associated JMS message group.

I know I give up ownership of the group by shutting down the corresponding consumer. However, that would mean I'd lose ownership of all groups associated with that consumer and not just the one for which I just unloaded the cached data.

Is there a way of giving up ownership of a specific group on the consumer side?

A broker-independant way would be preferable but I'd settle for an ActiveMQ specific solution if that is the only way. Also, feel free to suggest how this might be done with your favorite message broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this right now without closing the consumer. 
Consumer != connection btw - so why aren't you using multiple consumers per connection - one per group ?